# Errors on my page when I try to use CSS

Tags: html, css

Line 8, Column 23: document type does not allow element "STYLE" here 

If I try to take the line out the format isnt correct, if I leave it in http://validator.w3.org/check gives me an error. Can someone explain or maybe give me the correct way of doing this.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<title>Randy's first html web page !</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
body
h1

{
background-color:#6495aa;
margin-right:1350px;
}

h2
{
background-color:#b0c4de;
margin-right:1350px;
}

p
{
background-color:#649fff;
margin-right:1350px;
}
div
{
background-color:#efffff;
}

</style>


<h1> Hello Professor</h1>
<h2> By: Randy White</h2>
<P> I haven't done anything like this before.</P> 
<P>Seems to be ok</P> 
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Month</th>
<th>Day</th>
<th>Year</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>December</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>2010</td>
</tr>
</table>
<a href="http://www.google.com">Visit Google!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style tag should be in the head tag.

Comment: I have to wait a certain time limit. As soon as it allows me I will click the checkmark

Answer (score 0):

`style` element can **only** be a child of `head`.